# Parsing JSON with Jackson Java

Tags: java, json, string, parsing, jackson

I have a problem while parsing JSON with Jackson. I have a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) object, wrapped by another.

Here is my code:

```
in main:
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<ItemBean> mpl2 = mapper.readValue(col.toString(),new TypeReference<List<ItemBean>>() {});
my POJO class:

public class ItemBean implements Serializable {
    private List<Item> items;
    @JsonProperty("Item")
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}

public class Item implements Serializable{
    public String field1;
    public Integer field2;

    public static final class Field3 extends GenericJson {
        private String subfield1;
        private String subfield2;
    }
}
```

And here is the thrown exception:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "item" (Class bean.item), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@101b6d56; line: 4, column: 16] (through reference chain: bean.ItemBean["items"]->bean.Item["item"])
```

JSON looks in a such way:

```
["{\n
            \"items\":
        [
        \n  {
        \n \"item\": {
        \n    \"field1\": \"val1\",
        \n    \"field2\": \"val2\",
        \n    \"field3\": [
                        \n     {
                        \n      \"subfield1\": subval
                         \n      \"subfield2\": subval
                        \n     }
                        \n    ]
                        \n   }
                        \n  },
        \n \"item\": {
        \n    \"field1\": \"val1\",
        \n    \"field2\": \"val2\",
        \n    \"field3\": [
                        \n     {
                        \n      \"subfield1\": subval
                         \n      \"subfield2\": subval
                        \n     }
                        \n    ]
                        \n   }
                        \n  },
        \n \"item\": {
        \n    \"field1\": \"val1\",
        \n    \"field2\": \"val2\",
        \n    \"field3\": [
                        \n     {
                        \n      \"subfield1\": subval
                         \n      \"subfield2\": subval
                        \n     }
                        \n    ]
                        \n   }
                        \n  },


etc......   may I haven't closed brackets correctly, but they are correct :)
            }
        ]
    "]
```

POJO totally repeat the fields of the JSON object.

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense: Your JSON is an array of (strange) strings - this will not parse with neither the code from the question, nor your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my own method, which parses JSON of such a structure.

Here is the code:

```
public static List parseList(String jsonInput, Class clazz) {
    List result = new LinkedList();
    JSONArray json = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonInput);
    JSONObject items = (JSONObject)json.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONArray dataArrayJSON = (JSONArray)items.getJSONArray("items");

    for (int i = 0; i < dataArrayJSON.size(); i++) {
        result.add(JSONObject.toBean(dataArrayJSON.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("item"), clazz));
    }
    return result;
}
```

The problem was that items are in the array and items is the only element. items in its turn, is also an array, thus I used the `dataArrayJSON.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("item")` construction.